# Is totally ordered monoid $(Q,+, \leq)$ order isomorphic to $(Q^+,+, \leq)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Sorry if this is a trivial question.

I am trying to see whether there is can be an order-isomorphism between totally ordered monoids $(Q,+,\leq)$ and $(Q^+,+,\leq)$.

I tried to find whether there is isomorphism (potentially not ordered) between monoids $(Q,+)$ and $(Q^+,+)$ as a start, but could not find anything.

Any reading materials are appreciated as well. Please let me know if the question is not well-formed.

Thank you!

Comment: $(Q^+,+)$ is **not** a group - it doesn't have inverses (or even an identity element if $Q^+$ is the *positive*, as opposed to merely *nonnegative*, rationals). Did you mean $(\mathbb{Q}^+,\times)$ instead? Regardless, under any interpretation of the question I can think of, the element $-1$ of $Q$ is going to yield a counterexample to isomorphism.

Comment: Oh you are right. $(Q^+, +)$ is not a group. I am actually interested in monoids. Updated the question for that. And I mean non-negative rationals by $Q^+$.

Comment: One of them is a group and one of them isn't, so they can't be isomorphic as monoids.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!